# Getting PostSharp 6.0.32 and Log4Net 2.0.0 to log at a custom level

Tags: postsharp

We are using PostSharp with Log4Net as a back end. I am trying to get PostSharp to log at a different level to our manually added log statements which are at DEBUG level.

I've tried setting the postsharp.config file option below:

```
  <LoggingProfile Name="default" IncludeSourceLineInfo="True">
    <DefaultOptions>
      <LoggingOptions Level="Trace"/>
    </DefaultOptions>
  </LoggingProfile>
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I've overridden the Log4NetLoggingBackend to try and intercept the Trace level but it seems that when setting the PostSharp level to Trace, it doesn't hit any of the custom backend code.

Have I missed out a crucial step?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration snippet shown in the question looks correct. Please note, however, that in the configuration file you set the PostSharp logging level that is then mapped to the logging level of the target logging back-end (log4net in this case). Both `LogLevel.Trace` and `LogLevel.Debug` map to the `Debug` level in log4net because the log4net library doesn't offer `Trace` level.

You can try to set level to `Info` to test that your configuration file works as expected.